# JQGrid URL Sometimes including controller in call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I have this code in a javascript function in my ASP.NET MVC application...

```
   jQuery("#SomeResultsGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'SomeSearch.mvc/SomeSearchResultsGridEventHandler', ...
```

This loads on my default page and raises just fine (fiddler confirmed).  Now, if I go to that default page (via a Html.ActionLink), the url that posts after load now looks like SomeSearch.mvc/SomeSearch.mvc/SomeSearchResultsGridEventHandler.  Anyone know why and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a relative URI, so the URI will be treated as relative to the current location. You can put a `/` at the start like this to make it an absolute path:

```
jQuery("#SomeResultsGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '/SomeSearch.mvc/SomeSearchResultsGridEventHandler', ...
```

Problem is, now it won't work in a virtual folder. We handle that with a JS routine which knows about the site root using info in the Site.Master.